# change versioning in a project libgdx and load with Application Loader

Tags: java, android, libgdx, versioning, application-loader

I'm doing a play in libgdx and should change version to avoid the problem of redundancy version of itunes connect , loading with Application Loader and can not figure out how to change the version number , are andanto in AndroidManifest.xml and put :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mygame.game.android"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="2" >
```

and also

```
allprojects {
apply plugin: "eclipse"
apply plugin: "idea"

version = '1.1'
ext {
    appName = "My Game"
    gdxVersion = '1.7.0'
    roboVMVersion = '1.8.0'
    box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
    ashleyVersion = '1.6.0'
    aiVersion = '1.6.0'
}
```

but when I do the IPA with ROBOVM keeps giving me the error Redundancy version , although it has set 1.1 or 1.0 .
Solutions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up Android and iOS.

To change iOS versions edit the `robovm.properties` in your ios sub project.

You need to increment `app.build` and change `app.version` for each build you upload.